# MySQL RegExp how to match all given letters in any position

Tags: mysql, regex, arrays, sql-like

**How can this be done?**

Having an array of strings like this:

- axa
- ttx
- tox
- atx
- tax
- xat

How do i find all letters of the input string '**tax**' standing in all possible positions?
The result must be:

- atx
- tax
- xat

Thought it would be easy using a REGEXP, but stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
txa|tax|axt|atx|xta|xat
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/MOXXA-TNLLZ3Hj86)

Honestly, you can probably do it without "hard coding" it. However, the regex will prob be longer then this because there isn't many permutations of tax.

```
^(?=.*[t])(?=.*[x])(?=.*[a])[tax]{3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/vjSv8rABEpvQkFka)

This is the actual not "hardcoded" way.

Comment: There are six combinations of the letters, not three.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wow, i feel stupid haha i just went off the OPs question.

Comment: Seems to be working, but MySQL gives an error on '?=' saying: Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: @user2773387 tits it's because MySql doesnt support postive lookaheads.